# Sencha Touch's loadmask customization

Tags: css, extjs, sencha-touch

Example of Sencha Touch loadmask: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXBHO.jpg)

Is there any way to customize the loadmask properties without needing to create a new one? I want to increase the size of the darker grey box (i think its the inner-mask right?) because i want to use html to make the loadmask looks better. But with box that has a size like that, there's little thing that you can do to make the loadmask looks better.

```
masked: {
          xtype: 'loadmask',
          message: 'Now Loading..',
        }
```

How would i set that darker grey box size? I tried with height and width but that one modifies the whole loadmask size, not the darker grey box area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i tried some, here is the result.

**Solution 1**

```
{
   xtype: 'loadmask',
   id : 'testMask',
   message: 'Now Loading..'
}
```

*CSS*

```
div#testMask{
    font-size: 20.95px;
}
```

it's working but note that it will increases font size.

**Solution 2**

*CSS*

```
.x-mask .x-loading-spinner-outer {
    min-width: 20.5em !important;
    height: 19.5em !important;
}
```

it's also working, but it overrides the existing style.